# Correct Output for java method

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create a method that counts the number of times a specified character appears in a given string, by printing the sentence and the specified character and its count.

This is what I have completed so far:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program4 {

public int count ( String sentence, char letter)
 {
   int times = 0;
   for (int x=0;x<sentence.length();x++)
 {
if (sentence.charAt(x) ==letter){times++;}

 }
return times;
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Program4 program4 = new Program4();
}
program4.count("Hello World",'o');
scan.close();
}
}
```

I understand I need a "system.output.println" but I don't know what value goes inside to get the output I am looking for. I would appreciate any help, I am beginner with java. Thank you.

Comment: Surely this is literally page 2 of the tutorial, right after "Hello, world." ?

Comment: Okay, now, where do you create a `program4` variable? Your count method returns something... Why don't you print that?

Comment: Have you heard of indentation of code to make it human readable? You should try it, because *we* are all human, and you're asking for our help. Also, when you do, maybe you'd see why your code won't compile, e.g. because **you have no class**. Perhaps you should (re)read the first chapter of you Java guide; you know, the chapter with the *simple* "Hello World" program.

Comment: Suggestion: Download an IDE, don't write your code in notepad. It'll format your code and show any errors

Comment: Is this code inside a class?  It seems to me that you'll need to instantiate that class if you want to call the `count` method.

Answer (score 0):

it works, you had compile time error in code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program4 {

    public int count(String sentence, char letter) {
        int times = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < sentence.length(); x++) {
            if (sentence.charAt(x) == letter) {
                times++;
            }

        }
        return times;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Program4 program4 = new Program4();

        int timesCount =    program4.count("Hello World", 'o');
         System.out.println("count is :" + timesCount);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just posted the rest of my code too

Comment: please click on the tick button if my answer solves your question